# error from Akka shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[play-dev-mode] java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: playframework-2.6

When I start the `play/scala` application in `IntelliJ`, I get the following error `Uncaught error from thread [play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2]: null, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[play-dev-mode]
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)`

The error happens at the following line of code `lazy val httpRequestHandler: HttpRequestHandler = new DefaultHttpRequestHandler(router, httpErrorHandler, httpConfiguration, httpFilters: _*)`. This is not my code though. The first entry of my code which I can see in stack trace (apploader.scala) is

`lazy val userController = new UserController(credentialsProvider,application.configuration, utilities,userRepository, userTokenRepository,mailerService,controllerComponents, silhouetteJWTProvider,messagesApi,langs)`

The `UserController` is defined as follows:
`class UserController (credentialsProvider:CredentialsProvider,config:Configuration, utilities:HelperMethods, userRepo: UsersRepository,userTokenRepo:UserTokenRepository, mailerService:MailerService, cc: ControllerComponents, silhouette: Silhouette[JWTEnv],messagesApi: MessagesApi,langs:Langs)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc){`

I have seen solutions on SO which shows how to disable the feature ([disable akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error for actorsystem in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649527/disable-akka-jvm-exit-on-fatal-error-for-actorsystem-in-java)) but I don't think it is a good idea to allow `jvm` to run for `StackOverflowError`. I don't know what is causing the issue though.

Why am I getting the error? To me, it seems the code is running in some sort of loop because the stack trace is repetitive.

```
Server started, use Alt+D to stop

practice question Javascript repo is practice_questions_javascript_tag
practice question html repo is practice_questions_html_tag
[warn] c.d.d.c.Cluster - You listed localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 in your contact points, but it wasn't found in the control host's system.peers at startup
database will connect with keyspace Some(codingjedi)
(keyspace is ,codingjedi)
user repo is users
app loader: csrf values: csrfToken, Some(CJCsrfCookie), CJCsrfHeader
Uncaught error from thread [play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2]: null, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[play-dev-mode]
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler$(Application.scala:321)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.httpRequestHandler(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application(Application.scala:324)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.application$(Application.scala:323)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application$lzycompute(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext.application(ApplicationLoader.scala:122)
    at app.AppComponents.userController$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userController(AppLoader.scala:357)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.userWSRoutes(AppLoader.scala:377)
    at app.AppComponents.router$lzycompute(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:379)
    at app.AppComponents.router(AppLoader.scala:128)
    at play.api.BuiltInComponents.httpRequestHandler(Application.scala:321)
    at ...
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't debugged the issue completely yet but it seems that I should be using the `configuration` object provided by `BuiltInComponentsFromContext` instead of `application.configuration`. I changed the `userRepository` definition to the following and the code worked.

`lazy val userController = new UserController(credentialsProvider,configuration, utilities,userRepository, userTokenRepository,mailerService,controllerComponents, silhouetteJWTProvider,messagesApi,langs)`